# Protobuf requires at least C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-code, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf file with below content and generated pb.h & pb.cc files out of them.

**Proto file content:**

```
syntax = "proto3";

package person;

message Person{
    string name = 1;
    map<string, string> mp = 2;
}
```

I have a main.cpp file where i am trying to import generated code however i am getting **"Protobuf requires at least C++11"** error.

**main.cpp content:**

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include "./person.pb.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
  
  string greeting = "bishnu";
  cout << greeting;
  map<string, string> m;
  return 0;
}
```

I am using macbook, intel chip and Visual Studio Code IDE.

I dont know what the issue is. Can somebody help me get this sorted? Any pointer to right document would also be helpful.

**Code Compilation:**
I am using code runner extension and it's compiling using "g++ main.cpp -o main" command.

Also, Even before compiling i can see error in #incude statement by IDE.

Comment: You have to compile the code as C++ as defined by the 2011 revision of the ISO standard. How do you compile it? What are the language settings?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=compile+C%2B%2B11+visual+studio -- that should probably help you solve this.

Comment: @user17732522 - Yes, i am using Visual Studio Code. Sorry for the confusion, updated the question.

Comment: What is the question about? How to select the ISO standard in given IDE?

Comment: How are you compiling the code?

Comment: "g++ main.cpp -o main" command is used to compile the code.

Comment: it seems, i need to force c++11 version in protoc config before generating pb.h/pb.cc file. (Bit new to this, going through comments...allow me sometime :) ) thanks

Comment: just use `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main` instead